# Loop on array of JSON data

Tags: angular

I call a function who draw a line each time I loop an array of JSON data. When I debug, it works well, but make me one loop too much, where it cancels all my previous loops and give me an error. How can I cancel this last loop ?

When I debug, I can see all the lines drawn until the last loop.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
//On recup les familles
this.serviceFam.getAllFamilles().subscribe(data => {
  this.listeFamilles = data;
    for (let f of this.listeFamilles._embedded.familles) {
      this.draw("#" + f.nom, this.arriel1, {dateDimension: false, color:
        "teal", labelFormat: "%Y"})
    }

}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
}
```

EDIT :

I've tested it so it's not a problem of loop but I don't know why first it draw me all the lines but at the end it gives me an error and erase them.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's that or not but when I debug, the only thing I can see is this message : ReferenceError: err is not defined.
The console don't show me nothing

Comment: Share your json that you get, and will try to replicate locally. Don't need all data, just a anonymised subset of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why that last iteration will cause the error, but in order to prevent that last iteration from the `for..of` loop from happening, you can try to access the index within each iteration of the for..of loop by using [Array.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries).

```
for (let [index, f] of this.listeFamilles._embedded.familles.entries()) {
  if (index === (this.listeFamilles._embedded.familles.length - 1)) {
    break;
  }
  this.draw("#" + f.nom, this.arriel1, {dateDimension: false, color:
    "teal", labelFormat: "%Y"})
}
```